# Deducing charges from a Lagrangian, in supersymmetric quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, noethers-theorem

I'm trying to read through [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(85)90500-0) paper called "Supersymmetric Ground State Wavefunctions". Half way down page 4, is says

> "We begin by reviewing Witten's original model which is defined by the Lagrangian
> \begin{align*}
> L = \frac{1}{2} \dot{x}^2 - \frac{1}{2}(W')^2 + i \hbar \bar{\psi} \dot{\psi} - \hbar W'' \bar{\psi}\psi.\tag{2.4}
> \end{align*}
> Here $x$ is the real coordinate and $W(x)$ the superpotential. Also, we use overdots to denot the time differntiation while primes denote differentiation with respect to $x$. From Noether's theorem, we obtain the charges
> $$\begin{align*}
> Q &= \psi(p + iW') \\
>  \bar{Q} &= \bar{\psi}(p - i W'),\tag{2.5}
> \end{align*}$$
> where $p = \dot{x}$ is the momentum conjugate to $x$."

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120906231820id_/http://zimp.zju.edu.cn:80/%7Ehep/LHC/DynamicalSUSYBreaking_Witten.pdf) is the Witten paper they reference when they mention his original model.

1. I would like to verify these charges do follow from Noether's theorem. To deduce those charges, must we not first note the symmetry of $L$? If so, what is it in this case?
2. I'm also a bit confused about how to think about this Lagrangian. Is it a single boson and two fermions? The boson is $x(t)$? Are $\psi, \bar{\psi}$ functions of $t$ (or $x$)?

(3.) Incidentally, I don't see this exact Lagrangian in the referenced Witten paper. The closest thing I see starts on page 24, but looks to me to be quite different to the above. If I'm just not seeing the link, I would appreciate someone pointing the connection out to me please.

If it's not already clear, I'm only starting to learn about SUSY. So there's no doubt plenty of basic stuff I am not aware of.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527459/supercharge-in-mathcaln-1-supersymmetric-quantum-mechanics-and-noethers-th). To find the susy  symmetries, (anti-)commute Q with your variables....

Comment: (2.11) of C&H is (29) of W, but you must redefine W' to W ...

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your first comment. And for the second, the two equations also differ in that one has matrices, and one has grassmann variables.

Comment: The ψs in W are wavefunctions acted upon, normalized to 1, but omitted: $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are perfectly fine Grassman variables, so the supercharges Q are fermionic. In C&H, the Grassman variables include this normalization in *their* different ψs, as the extant answer indicates: a representation. The first comment asks you to compute $[Q,\psi]\propto \delta \psi$, etc, to verify Noether's theorem, that you appear conflicted about...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. For conservation laws, it is easier (and more precise!) to consider the quantum mechanical Hamiltonian operator formulation than the Lagrangian classical formulation. Due to
   $$2\hat{H}~=~\{\hat{Q},\hat{\overline{Q}}\}_+~\stackrel{(2.5)+(2.6)}{=}~\hat{p}^2 + W^{\prime}(\hat{x})^2 +\hbar W^{\prime\prime}(\hat{x})[\hat{\overline{\psi}},\hat{\psi}],\tag{2.7}$$
   and $$\hat{Q}^2~\stackrel{(2.5)+(2.6)}{=}~0~\stackrel{(2.5)+(2.6)}{=}~\hat{\overline{Q}}^2,\tag{2.1}$$
   it follows from the super Jacobi identity for the super-commutator that the supercharges $\hat{Q}$ and $\hat{\overline{Q}}$ commute with the Hamiltonian operator
   $$ \begin{align} 4[\hat{Q},\hat{H}]~\stackrel{(2.7)}{=}~&2[\hat{Q},\{\hat{Q},\hat{\overline{Q}}\}_+]~\stackrel{\text{Jac.Id.}}{=}~[\{\hat{Q},\hat{Q}\}_+,\hat{\overline{Q}}]~\stackrel{(2.1)}{=}~0,\cr
   4[\hat{\overline{Q}},\hat{H}]~\stackrel{(2.7)}{=}~&2[\hat{\overline{Q}},\{\hat{\overline{Q}},\hat{Q}\}_+]~\stackrel{\text{Jac.Id.}}{=}~[\{\hat{\overline{Q}},\hat{\overline{Q}}\}_+,\hat{Q}]~\stackrel{(2.1)}{=}~0, \end{align}$$
   and are hence conserved quantities.

   To connect this to a classical Lagrangian formalism, one should consider a super-version of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. $x(t)$ is a boson, while $\psi(t)$ and $\overline{\psi}(t)$ are fermions in 0+1D.
3. The Pauli matrix eqs. (28) and (29) in chapter 6 of Ref. 1 are essentially a 2-dimensional representation of eqs. (2.5) and (2.7), respectively.

References:

1. E. Witten, [*Dynamical breaking of supersymmetry*](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=witten+dynamical+breaking+supersymmetry+pdf), [Nucl. Phys B185 (1981) 513](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90006-7).